# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
Select S.sname
From    suppliers s
where not exists (
(select * from parts p where p.color = 'red')  ; all red parts
except
(select c.pid from catalog c, parts p where c.sid = s.sid
and c.pid = p.pid and p.color = 'red'))


select  p.pname
from    parts p. catalog c, suppliers s
where   p.pid = c.pid and c.sid = s.sid
AND s.sname = 'S1'

AND not exists (  # another supplier
select * from catalog c1, suppliers s1
where p.pid = c1.pid and c1.sid = s1.sid
AND s1.sname <> 'S1')
```

When I am executing the above two queries it is showing SQL command not properly ended

Comment: you need to terminate each statement with `;`  (plus the embedded `; all red parts` and ` # another supplier` are wrong as well

Comment: and there is no except in Oracle's SQL. Commenting out is performed by two dashes(`--`) for only one line, by `/*   */`  for multiple lines, but not by  `#` or `;`

Answer (score 1):

Probably because they are invalid; what are those

- `; all red parts except` and
- `# another supplier`

supposed to do? Comments, perhaps? In Oracle, you'd use `--` or enclose comments into `/* ... */`.

This is, probably, somewhat better:

First query:

```
Select S.sname 
From suppliers s 
where not exists ( (select * 
                    from parts p 
                    where p.color = 'red'
                   ) 
                    minus 
                   (select c.pid 
                    from catalog c, parts p 
                    where c.sid = s.sid 
                      and c.pid = p.pid 
                      and p.color = 'red'
                   )
                 );
```

Second query:

```
select p.pname 
from parts p, catalog c, suppliers s 
where p.pid = c.pid 
  and c.sid = s.sid 
  AND s.sname = 'S1'
  AND not exists (select * 
                   from catalog c1, suppliers s1 
                   where p.pid = c1.pid 
                     and c1.sid = s1.sid 
                     AND s1.sname <> 'S1'
                 );
```